# Are there swearing euphemisms in Latin?

Tags: euphemism

In Finnish it is possible to swear indirectly by replacing the swear word with a euphemism or perhaps a more innocent similar-sounding word.
This is most common in exclamations like "oh [enter expletive]!", and most people will understand which word is left unsaid.
Are there similar things in Latin from any era?
One can swear in Latin, but are there more innocent or less offensive variants for them?

Comment: The English term for these is "minced oath". The Wikipedia article with that title has some examples from Greek, but not from Latin.